# I need help to Aggregate for mongoDb Chat App to receive latest message from each related chat

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, aggregate, aggregation

I'm making a chat app, and there will be only one conversation between two person so I didn't make conversation table or ID and the way I want to show list of chats to clients will be like this:

I will get the latest message related to each conversation, conversations are filtered by sender/receiver ID's,

So if there is 2 message in database and the first one has this data :

```js
{
    sender: "User.x.ID",
    receiver: "User.y.ID",
    msg: "How are you?",
},
{
    sender: "User.y.ID",
    receiver: "User.x.ID",
    msg: "Good thanks, and you?",
},
```

The latest message will be `"Good thanks, and you?"`

This my `messageSchema`:

```js
{
    sender: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
    },
    receiver: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
    },
    usersRelated: {
        type: Array,
    },
    msg: {
        type: String,
    }
}
```

This is my code:

```js
const Chats = await Message.aggregate([
    { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } },
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                usersRelated: [req.user.id],
            },
        },
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                sender: "$sender",
                receiver: "$receiver",
            },
            messages: {
                $top: {
                    sortBy: { createdAt: -1 },
                    output: "$$ROOT",
                },
            },
        },
    },
    { $replaceWith: "$messages" },
])
```

And it returns both of the messages which I don't want, I only want the latest message which will be : `"Good thanks, and you?"`.

The reason behind of my need is :

I am trying to show the lists of chats with the preview of latest message same as most of chat apps.

So if you are logged in as `User X` what you will see in your list of chat will be one chat with `User Y` and they responded to you: `"Good thanks, and you?"` and if you click on the chat, then I will load all of the messages related to this two user which will be like this :

```
User X said : How are you?

User Y Said : Good thanks, and you?
```

Comment: Instead a sequence of `$unwind` and `$group` you may use [$setWindowFields](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Can you show me how to do it please?

Comment: What do you mean by "latest message"? The last message based on what?  `_id`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit `createdAt` but the catch is if the latest message is from sender x and receiver y I don't want the other message which is from sender y and receiver x as it will be the same chat and its not the latest message it will be 2nd message after latest. (my current code is doing this for me but it doesn't get sort by createdAt)

Comment: I could receive their id from current code and then make a loop from the ID's that I have to receive the latest message for each user but it will reduce the performance of the app as it will send many request to mongoDB if I do that.

Comment: `{ $sort: { createdAt: -1 } }` is not needed when you use `$top` where you specify the order. And `$expr` is also not needed, just use `{ usersRelated: [req.user.id] }`. However, are you sure the order of elements is the same in `usersRelated` and `req.user.id`?

Comment: After your edit, the sample data is pointless. What means "first" and "latest"? The data in a database does not have any order. Imagine it is just a bucket full of messages - which one is the first?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit `{ usersRelated: [req.user.id] }` contains to element but when I check for only one element it still works too, so I think it only checks does it contain the value or not, but If i use `$eq` then I should use the exact same elements.

Comment: I think you would rather need `{ usersRelated: {$in: [req.user.id] } }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $group: {
         _id: { $sortArray: { input: ["$sender", "$receiver"], sortBy: 1 } },
         messages: {
            $top: {
               sortBy: { createdAt: -1 },
               output: "$$ROOT"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $replaceWith: "$messages" },
])
```

`$top` was introduced in MongoDB version 5.2. If you run an older version, then try this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: { $sortArray: { input: ["$sender", "$receiver"], sortBy: 1 } },
         messages: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
      }
   },
   { $replaceWith: "$messages" },
])
```

Comment: I tried the second code, then I added `$match` and now it returns the last 2 messages related to each same sender and user and I want only the latest message not 2 of them, this is the code ```js {
 $match: {
  $expr: {
   $or: [
    { $eq: ["$sender", req.user._id] },
    { $eq: ["$receiver", req.user._id] },
   ],
  },
 },
},

{
 $group: {
  _id: { sender: "$sender", receiver: "$receiver" },
  messages: {
   $top: {
    sortBy: { createdAt: -1 },
    output: "$$ROOT",
   },
  },
 },
},
{ $replaceWith: "$messages" },``` but it also shoes the latest message which is nice.

Comment: Both of the codes works the same with `$match` added but I need them to work like mine and only return the latest message related to each same sender, receiver (if sender is x and receiver is y, then I don't want the next message from sender y and receiver x since its the same chat and its the message before latest message)

Comment: Please edit your question, instead of adding a comment. Still not clear what you mean by "latest message"

Comment: Edited, Please take a look, and I also explained what I mean by latest message hopefully it will be helpful, Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe try to group by `_id: { $sortArray: { input: ["$sender", "$receiver"], sortBy: 1 } }` This one will group be conversation between two people

Comment: It's working thanks a lot `_id: { $sortArray: { input: ["$sender", "$receiver"], sortBy: 1 } }`